# How to rerun cmake custom command, when one of its dependencies becomes "dirty"?

Tags: cmake

I have python script that is run through add_custom_command in my project, this script analyzes target sources and generate additional one for the target.

```
get_target_property(TARGET_SOURCES ${target} SOURCES)
add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static_init/generated/${target}/static_init.cpp
     COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} myscript.py
     DEPENDS ${TARGET_SOURCES}
     VERBATIM)
target_sources( "${target}" PRIVATE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static_init/generated/${target}/static_init.cpp" )
```

I need my script to rerun when one of sources becomes "dirty" (e.g. one of included headers is changed, probably this file is in another target and it is not guaranteed that another target will be rebuild on header change). As we use Ninja, IMPLICIT_DEPENDS isn't available for us, so it looks DEPFILE property is the way to do it, but I cannot understand, how can I get one for all ${TARGET_SOURCES}?

It doesn't seem to me that ninja will generate something like that automatically, I cannot write it by hands, as it will require to recursively analyze all includes during cmake run. Or maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To get dependencies of a source you have to compile it. Just depend on the target. I would do:

```
add_custom_target(target_objects OBJECT all_source_files_for_your_target)
add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static_init/generated/${target}/static_init.cpp
     COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} myscript.py
     DEPENDS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:target_objects>
     VERBATIM
)
add_custom_library/executable("${target}" PRIVATE 
     ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static_init/generated/${target}/static_init.cpp
)
link_target_libraries("${target}" PRIVATE target_objects)
```

That way the dependencies are linear.

Comment: Instead of `link_target_libraries` you probably mean `target_link_libraries`, and instead of `add_custom_library` - `add_library` without PRIVATE keyword.

Comment: Splitting into different target will bring me many problems, so it's not a good way for me.

Comment: I guess you need to make sure the headers are part of the `add_custom_command(DEPENDS)`.